# Binding a Telerik Menu to a stored procedure in MVC3 with Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, menu, razor, telerik

I am using the Telerik menu control in MVC3 with Razor. I noticed that the documentation on the Telerik website says it is possible but does not show how to bind the menu control to a stored procedure. 
Has anyone had success doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Data binding to a model](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/menu/databindingtomodel) seems the best way. So just design a view model that will represent your menu data and simply have your controller action call the stored procedure and populate this view model from the results of it.

Answer (score 0):

It depends which ORM you are using. What telerik controls required is a model you populate you model using stored procedure as described by the ORM you are using and rest is the same. This [link](http://jalpesh.blogspot.com/2010/08/binding-custom-entity-class-to-stored.html) may give you some starting idea